# How to print out key values in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, dictionary, key, echo

Let's say for example I have the following code:

```
arr=([j1]=3 [j2]=2 [j3]=1)
```

How do I print out the key values (j1, j2, j3)?

I tried this:

```
for key in ${!arr[@]}; do
    echo ${key}
done
```

It printed out the following:

```
0
```

How do I print out all of the key values and not the index number?

EDIT1:

I tried some of the suggestions and my full code is now as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Suggestion 2
declare -A arr

arr=([j1]=3 [j2]=2 [j3]=1)


#My original code
for key in ${!arr[@]}; do
    echo ${key}
done


#Suggestion 1
for i in "${!arr[@]}"
do
    echo "key: $i"
    echo "value: ${arr[$i]}"
done
```

I have two for loops that theoretically should print out my key values, but I am still getting the following:

```
0
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your code in EDIT1 works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is OK. You just forgot one line:

```
declare -A arr
```

Else, `arr` is not considered as an associative array but an indexed array and each index is seen as a arithmetic expression (i.e. your array initialization evaluates to `arr=([0]=3 [0]=2 [0]=1)`).

```
$ arr=([j1]=3 [j2]=2 [j3]=1)
$ for key in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo "${key}"; done
0
$ unset arr

$ declare -A arr
$ arr=([j1]=3 [j2]=2 [j3]=1)
$ for key in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo "${key}"; done
j2
j3
j1
```

(Leading `$` is the shell prompt of course)

Comment: hmmm I'm still getting just a single 0 printed out

Comment: I added my code above in an edit, so you can see it.

Comment: I've typed your code exactly as it appears and I am still getting a single 0. I am clueless as to what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: @MoreFoam What is the version of your bash interpreter? Thashin: no semicolon needed

Comment: Using the bash --version command, I see I have "GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release"

Comment: @MoreFoam Your version is correct. Associative arrays appeared in bash 4. That's quite weird. Your array seems like an indexed array. Can you confirm that arr[0]=1?

Comment: Weird thing: I retyped the script so it is identical to my original and now it works. They both have same extension (.sh) and same exact code. Only difference is one is titled "test.sh" and the other is "test2.sh".. Idk.. I must have messed something up.. not sure what, though. Anyways thank you for your time, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${array[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: This code returns the same thing mine did. A single value: 0